# How do you get your Google+ profile displayed in the right hand sidebar of the Google search results page?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-plus

Does anyone know how to get your Google+ profile displayed in the right hand sidebar of the Google search results page? As in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[UPDATED]**

**For Google+ business pages (local)**

Here's a guide: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713911?hl=en

1. Sign in to Google+ (you’ll have to create a Google+ profile if you don’t already have one).
2. Click *Pages* under *Home* on the left.
3. Click the *Create a page* button in the upper right.
4. Select the *Local Business* or *Place* category.
5. Enter the name or address of your business and select your business if it appears in the drop-down menu.

If you don't see your business listed in the menu, click *No, these are not my businesses* or *I've correctly entered the business*.

You'll then be prompted to enter some details for your business. Make sure you enter an accurate, complete street address and a phone number which reaches your business directly.

After you complete your business information, click *Submit*.

You will have one or two verification options. You can also choose to skip verification and return to your page's dashboard at https://plus.google.com/dashboard to complete the process later.

**For Google+ business pages (non-local)**

This is the old verification link:

[image: Screenshot showing Google messaging on verification requests]

**Apparently, verifying your page is much more of an automated process now by Google.**

It's definitely a good idea to have your Google+ page linking to your website and vice-versa, maybe via a [Google+ badge](https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/#badge). Specially since it's written (as you can see in the picture) it says "*learn more about linking for Google+ pages*".

See here: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713826

Here are some links that I found with helpful information:

- Local Google+ pages: https://support.google.com/plus/topic/2566084
- Types of Google+ pages: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2659170?hl=en
- A blog post about the issue: http://www.virante.org/blog/2013/10/09/google-plus-page-verification-now-harder-get-still-possible/

**Original Answer:**

To have a business page appear on the right hand side of Google search results page, you will need to have a Google+ verified business page, which is symbolized by that small "v" next to the business name. To do such, you will need to have a Google+ business page verified by requesting it via this form: http://support.google.com/plus/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=page_verification&rd=1

Jack Lockyer's answer works for displaying a thumbnail image of your Google+ profile on search results **UNDER** the website title on the left side of the results, as seen [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986). And by that giant red arrow on your question, **that's not what you were looking for. That answer is incorrect.**

P.S.: I have done the verification myself for my business, and after less than a week, it was being displayed on search results.

Comment: The second link you included is the "authorship" link, which is something we also show, but it needs a different link-type than the publisher one (authorship is for personal profiles & individual articles, publisher is for the whole website & the Google+ Page).

Comment: @JohnMueller Thank you for clarifying that part John. I have never used that and was just trying to demonstrate the difference. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @guisasso I have a question. sometimes it displays wikipedia information, not Google plus. How to make it?

Comment: How recent was this answer updated? Google has significantly changed their integration between Google Search and Google+. I'm at a loss as to how to achieve the original question's intent.

Comment: @JustinSkiles The Google+ changes I have seen so far are related to the requirement of Google+ for some Google apps. If there is more... it would be good to know. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc This is what I have read recently. While not specifically about brands and such, I don't trust Google to leave anything alone with the amount of changes they're notorious for making. http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-links-and-reviews-dropped-from-google-search-results/141262/

Comment: @JustinSkiles Oh yes! I forgot about this. These just showed up on the SERP snippet. I am not sure it really helped the click through rates and took up valuable space. Google has been dropping the inclusions into the SERPs including author info, and what not that do not appear to move the needle.

Answer (score 11):

You will need to associate your Google Plus account with the webpage that you're searching for.

In you Google Plus account add the website in the 'contributor' section of your profile, then add the following tag to the header of your webpage:

```
<link rel="publisher" href="GOOGLE_PlUS_ACCOUNT_URL>
```

Wait a few days for Google to re-index your site and you should be away! Of course doing this doesn't *guarantee* that Google will include your profile in the search results.

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks very much. I'll give it a shot. 

"Ofcourse doing this doesn't guarantee that Google will include your profile in the search results." - yep, noted!

Comment: You need to make sure that you're linking to a Google+ Page, not a personal Google+ Profile, when using the rel=publisher markup. Using this markup to link to a personal profile will not work.