# Business not showing up on right hand side of google search

Tags: google, url, search, thumbnail

The business I work has currently has a verified business Google+ page and in the past this page has shown up as a thumbnail during Google searches. The thumbnail brings up basic information such as our picture and operating hours etc.

However, since verifying the business page, the thumbnail overview of our business does not seem to show up anymore. I have tried Google searching our business on several computers and it still just brings up the normal search results.

Is there a setting I need to activate in order for the thumbnail to appear?

*****EDITED NOTES

WE HAVE ALREADY VERIFIED AND SET UP OUR BUSINESS PAGE HOWEVER IT STILL DOES NOT APPEAR ON THE RIGHT HAND SIDE OF GOOGLE SEARCHES.

Comment: Please follow the guide in [this accepted answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39954/how-do-you-get-your-google-profile-displayed-in-the-right-hand-sidebar-of-the-g) and confirm if you have implemented everything necessary to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Geoff, we have already set up and verified our business as per what your link suggests, however it still does not appear on the right hand side of search results.