# How can I get my organization brand to appear to the right of Google search?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

This was originally marked as a duplicate, however, I believe it is necessary to ask again as the requirements to accomplish the intent have changed significantly in the years since. Previous answers possibly no longer apply after Google's recent changes.

What are the necessary steps to achieve what is shown in the image below?

Here's what I have done so far:

- Created Google+ business page for brand
- Linked and verified website to Google+ page
- Added schema.org "organization" ld+json tags to relevant pages

Yet, when I search for my brand "twolips dating", there is nothing shown to the right.

[image]

Comment: There's really no guarantee that it will, and likely depends on various signals, such as brand popularity, shares, and links... See this related question also, which was commented on by John Mueller (of Google):  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39954/how-do-you-get-your-google-profile-displayed-in-the-right-hand-sidebar-of-the-g?rq=1

Comment: Thanks dan. The mystery behind it is a bit annoying. And to make matters worse, I don't believe that either of the links provided in this question are still accurate since Google has recently scaled back integration between Google+ and Google Search.

Comment: No problem. There is a bit of mystery, and a frustrating wait... You might be right about Google placing less emphasis on Google+, and more on other signals and popular resources like Wikipedia, as answered in the question marked as a duplicate, which is unfortunately too similar, but hopefully others will contribute an answer there after seeing this - so check back there. Also, if you figure out anything that doesn't fit, add a comment back here and I'll open it back up for you to answer. Good luck.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Dan makes a good point. For your brand, you can likely create a Wikipedia page for the brand/company. As well, Google looks for other indications such as brand searches, brand mentions, co-occurrences with other similar brands, authoritative articles such as NY Times, etc. Also this sidebar mention is knowledge graph stuff that comes from trusted data driven web resources that can be parsed into a knowledge base and *not* from ordinary web pages. It pays to know where Google gets knowledge-graph data from and seek entries in those resources that are appropriate.

Comment: @JustinSkiles One of the strongest branding signals does not exist on your site and will prevent your site from getting sidebar status. You will need to add NAP (name, address, phone) information as well as e-mail contact (found it on the contact page with phone number in footer). I advise adding company name and address with the phone number using schema.org mark-up in your footer. Without this, you will not achieve your goals. Also you have a private registration and a host with a less than stellar reputation. Something to be aware of. This can slow things down for you.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks so much for the advice regarding contact information. I will try to improve on that front. Also, there isn't any content blocked by the registration, but you can't interact/post without an account, so that shouldn't affect crawlers (I hope). But I'm not sure what you mean about my host, can you elaborate?

Comment: @JustinSkiles Google can still see registration information even if it is private, so that is not an issue with Google. I keep a hacker, spam, scraper database and ENom is the leader in bad activity by a long shot. Sites are associated with other sites on a network. ENom, while not necessarily bad from a user standpoint, operates an unstable network. They exceed the #2 spot by over x4 (times) the amount of crap in my database. Google ranks site trust in part by the network and sites on the network. At some point, you may want to switch hosts to avoid trouble.

Comment: @closetnoc I'm actually hosting in Azure, enom is apparently the registrar even though I paid through namecheap. I guess namecheap is an enom reseller. I'll try to get everything transferred. Thanks.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Okay. It is just that your IP address came back as an ENom assigned IP address. I do not know Azure. And yes. Namecheap is ENom under another name. Just do things when it is comfortable to do so. Quality these days is paramount. Do not go for the cheap option when it is only a buck or two for something better. Again, not saying that Enom is bad for users. I have seen sites on networks bring down other sites. CDNs are good for this. Sites get delisted as a result. Amazing!!